# Converting from vim search to sed

Tags: command-line, vim, grep, sed

I have a long Latex document with many sections. I'd like to check that all sections of the document are filled in. So I search for any time there is a '}' ending a section title, somewhitespace, and then a '\' starting the next section (This is far from a perfect search, but it's fine by me.)

In vim I use

```
/}\_s\\
```

Which works fine. However, I'm struggling to replicate the search on the command line.

I'd normally use grep, but this is a multiline match so that's out. I have little experience with sed, but I've tried this:

```
sed -e '/\}\s\\/p' file.tex
```

and it gives me everything (presumably because it's printing the multiline that matches - the whole file)

How can I improve this sed command to give me only, say, first line of the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed`, like `grep`, processes the file line by line. Moreover, it prints everything, unless you specify the `-n` option (or you use the `d` command).

You can try Perl:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 while /(\}\s*\\)/g' file.tex
```

- `-0777` reads the whole file rather then reading it line by line